# Angular with querystring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

** angular newbie alert **

I have a web page that is called with several querystring values.

I would like to populate a couple of data binding areas with values coming in from the querystring.

```
<span class="username">{{firstName}}{{lastName}}</span>
```

and i am parsing the querystring using this

```
  var vars = [], hash;
  var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
  if (q != undefined) {
    q = q.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      hash = q[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[1]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
  }

  alert(vars['lastName']);
```

I am not sure how to actually drive the values into the data binding fields.

Comment: there's nothing `C#` here

Comment: there are plenty of Angular tutorials online have you tried looking at some and trying to understand how AngularJS works..?

Comment: Yes, the tuts are great...  but in the question, i have not found a solution that i have outlined above.  I placed a textbox at the bottom of the page, and updated the textbox with the value from the querystring, nothing was updated in the bound-data field - until i manually enter a value into the textbox by hand, and then it updates the {{lastName}}   so what i need to do is replace the part of putting the value into the textbox, the changing the text for it to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go with several portions from several tuts along with a hammer to get something into place.

That being said, placement of the code is particularly important.

a majority of the code has to be done at the beginning of the page, and in the head section.

the suggestion for the $location was a good one, but it seemed to fail each time i placed it into the code block.

Here is the primary code block...

```
  <script>

var dashboardApp = angular.module('dashboardApp', []);
dashboardApp.controller('userNameCtrl', function ($scope) {

  var vars = [], hash;
  var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
  if (q != undefined) {
    q = q.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      hash = q[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[1]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
  }

  $scope.firstName = vars['firstName'];
  $scope.lastName = vars['lastName'];
});
```

```
<body ng-app="dashboardApp">

<span class="username" ng-controller="userNameCtrl">{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</span>
```

This code block fails with no error messages, but it crashes way out, and blows out the remaining javascript block

```
    var dashboardApp = angular.module('dashboardApp', []);

dashboardApp.controller('userNameCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

  alert("First Name is - " + $location.search()['firstName']);

  var vars = [], hash;
  var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
  if (q != undefined) {
    q = q.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      hash = q[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[1]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
  }

  $scope.firstName = vars['firstName'];
  $scope.lastName = vars['lastName'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $location provider from angular.

You can do `var searchObject = $location.search();`

Then get key of this object. Like searchObject.lastName

angular.controller("ctrl",['$location',function($location){
  /**Ctrl code **/

}]);

Comment: I tried this direction the first time, but i get an error that $location is undefined.  both inside the jquery(document).ready code block and outside.

Comment: are you using angular ? you must inject $location inside you controller

Comment: yes - i added this code to verify it is working       <span class="username">{{firstName}}{{lastName}}{{1 + 2}}</span>     and 3 is displayed

Comment: please explain how DI would be implemented in the question

Comment: you would do angular.controller("ctrl",['$location',function($location){}]); Check answer